# Load testing with Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

I have debugged thru the process of getting an auth token, and i am able to pass an activity from a console application to a custom connector web api.  From there i need to pass the activity to my bot, however, this is where i am running into a problem.

When i send my payload to my bot service end point (https://localhost:3979/api/messages) i am getting a 500 internal service error. using Postman, i am able to debug into the bot service, and see that i am getting an error of

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Rest.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
```

following the stack trace, i see "Unexpected character while parsing...". This occurs during the following call.

```
await dialogContext.PostAsync("Testing 123");
```

If i use the payload that is sent from the emulator, it works properly. However, if i change ChannelId to "test" and my ServiceUrl to my custom connector service, i get the error mentioned above.

I am debugging all services locally to get the pipeline setup properly.

Custom Connector Service url is using SSL (https).

What piece of the puzzle am i missing?

Comment: Have you checked out this article on load testing your bot? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/load-testing-a-bot/

Comment: Yep, is where I got the general framework from. However, it seems my custom connector is missing some implementation. After further debugging, I see that the PostAsync sends a post message to the custom connector. Any ideas where I can find what all needs implemented for the custom connector?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to https://github.com/thirumathi/bottestvsts, where you will find an approach for doing load testing.

In particular, at https://github.com/thirumathi/bottestvsts/tree/master/BotCustomConnectorSvc you will find a custom implementation of the connector and the state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem i was having was in one of the responses.  When i returned an id value, it was already encoded, but when it passed through the apicontroller, it was encoded again, therefore, the bot framework was not able to parse it properly.

Instead of returning a string of json (hardcoded as in the sample), i created a ResourceResponse object from the bot framework (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/de/df8/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_resource_response.html) which only contains an ID field, but it's what was expected. This resolved my communication issue from custom connector to bot framework to custom connector.